# Filter JavaScript array based on object property from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays in JavaScript. One of which needs filtering based on a property from the other one.

I have a movies list such as this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
      name: 'Batman'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
      name: 'Spiderman'
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I then have another array which contains movies that a user has watched but they are within a nested object within the array as a relationship following the JSON API spec.

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'moviesWatched',
    attributes: {
      comment: 'Excellent film, would recommend to anyone who loves a action film!'
    },
    relationships: {
      movie: {
        data: {
           type: 'movies',
           id: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What I need to achieve is I need to cross reference the id from `watchList[].relationships.movie.data.id` with the first array. Obviously, this list is a lot longer in production but what I am hoping to achieve is to have a full list of movies which the use has watched with the name of the movie based off 2 arrays formatted like this to save me having to store needless data inside of the database.

The outcome of the array would be something along the lines of...

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
       name: 'Batman'
    },
    meta: {
      watched: false
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
      name: 'Spiderman'
    },
    meta: {
      watched: true
    }
  }
]
```

Here is what I have currently, which is working but I don't know if there is a better way to go about it...

```
movies.map((movie) => {
    const watched = watchedMovies.find((searchable) => {
        return searchable.relationships.movie.data.id === searchable.id;
    });

    movie.meta.watched = watched || false;

    return movie;
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't seem to be filtering anything; you just have an additional property `meta.watched` set to `true` or `false` for each movie in your first array. Also, what have you tried on your own?

Comment: @slider edited the question to have what I have currently coded

Answer (score 3):

Since you said the list can be long, you can extract the "watched" movie ids to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then set the `meta.watched` property of a movie based on whether or not its `id` is in the set:

```js
const movies = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
      name: 'Batman'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'movies',
    attributes: {
      name: 'Spiderman'
    }
  }
];

const watched = [{
  id: '1',
  type: 'moviesWatched',
  attributes: {
    comment: 'Excellent film, would recommend to anyone who loves a action film!'
  },
  relationships: {
    movie: {
      data: {
        type: 'movies',
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
}];

const watchedSet = new Set(watched.map(m => m.relationships.movie.data.id));
movies.forEach(movie => movie.meta = {watched: watchedSet.has(movie.id)});

console.log(movies);
```

Comment: Great answer, it's been a while since I've seen such a good use case for `new Set()`

Comment: Purely out of my own curiosity, what is the benefit here of using a Set instead of a plain array and indexOf? I know that a Set only has unique values but based on the question and data structure it looks like the same movie ID wouldn’t appear in more than one moviesWatched entry. Maybe I’m missing something. Nice answer otherwise though, upvoted.

Comment: @Andy The `Set` data structure allows us to test whether a value is in it (with `has`) in constant time (as opposed to liner time using a normal array and `indexOf`). While this constant time access is not guaranteed in the EcmaScript spec, it is constant time in most implementations (e.g. V8, Firefox). Therefore, the resulting time complexity of the code above with a set will be `O(n)`. But with an array and `indexOf`, it will be `O(mn)`.